# Is there a such thing as "too much tag wiki"?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Recently there was a flood of edits to the tag wiki for [x-files](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-files).

The original wiki entry was admittedly a bit lax, and needs improvement. But somewhere around revision 4 things went really off the rails. The tag wiki now lists the "central theme" for almost every episode of the show, plus (IMO) far too much information about the plot and character development for a tag wiki. (It's almost 100 lines line now.)

Is there a point at which these entries become so big they are counterproductive? I thought that the tag wiki was just supposed to be a summary of the tag's topic, enough to let someone know *how to use* the tag, not an attempt to explain the entire work?

I was going to roll this wiki back to somewhere around rev 4/5 but I don't want to start an edit war or meta argument, so I figured I'd ask first.

Answer (score 5):

From the editing page itself:

[image: What are Tag Wikis?]

The [x-files tag wiki](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/x-files/info) is not brief, has no links, and in my opinion is a bit beyond reasonably sized - largely because the space the list takes up, but the rest has its own issues:

It looks like whoever has been editing this doesn't want to link offsite, instead incorporating as much information as they can onto the page.  The list of plotlines is unnecessary ("many paranormal topics" would probably suffice, perhaps with a link to Wikipedia or an X-Files wiki) and the protagonist paragraph seems like it's trying to describe every aspect of the characters' personalities instead of just introducing them.  Actors should be removed, that's on Wikipedia, IMDB, and I'm sure many other places as well.

By including links and adding clear separation of plots/characters/out-of-universe information (antagonists just melds into filming locations if you're only skimming the page), the whole thing would become a lot easier to digest, without overwhelming the reader - it's supposed act as an introduction, not an endpoint.

For reference, here's the current entire thing (scaled down to 1/3rd the height):

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in comments above, I am the one who has been (re-)developing this tag wiki.  I'm not particularly resistant to linking off-site.  In any case, I have edited the wiki, mainly by removing the topic list (what you call plotlines) and by compressing the character info.

Answer (score 0):

Although I suspect I'm in the minority, I'm going to say that there shouldn't be such thing as “too much tag wiki”, as long a minimum standards are met:

In the case of the X-Files tag:

- **Is all the information on-topic?**

Yes, it's all about the subject at hand, the X-Files TV series and Films

- **Is there extraneous or unnecessary information?**

No, it's all relevant to the TV series and films.

- **Is it unnecessarily wordy?**

No, the wording seems relatively concise.

- **Is there overlap into another canon universe?**

No, it's all pretty well focused.